# Make ls command sort by file type (e.g. directories and file extension)

Tags: terminal, bash, sort

How do I make `ls` sort by file type (e.g. directories first and then by file extension)? The answers suggested in [(Super User) Make ls sort by file type](https://superuser.com/q/19781/44957) result in unknown option errors from `ls`.

Comment: Minor correction regarding your title: ls isn't a bash command; it's a standalone executable located at `/bin/ls` .

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As you've found out, the Darwin version of the `ls` command doesn't support the `-X | --sort=extension` option. This option is unique to the GNU version of `ls`.

You can obtain the GNU version of `ls` for your system. The easiest way to do this is through the [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) package manager and porting system. With Homebrew installed do:

```
brew install coreutils
```

to add the [GNU Core Utilities](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) package to your system. All the utilities will be prefixed with `g` so they don't collide with the default Darwin utils that OS X ships with.

With the GNU Core Utilites installed you can now do:

```
gls -X
```

And you'll see the output sorted as you desire.

If you want to use the GNU Core Utils instead of the utilities that come with OS X you can put the following line in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
source /usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.14/aliases
```

And you won't need to use the `g` prefix on the commands any more. I'll say this isn't an entirely safe thing to do as some of the GNU utils differ from the bash built-ins and Darwin tools in how they behave, enough so that they might screw up other things in your shell session. So do this with caution.

Answer (score 2):

Based on an answer in the [linked Super User article](https://superuser.com/questions/19781/make-ls-sort-by-file-type-then-name):

```
ls -l |sort -d -k 1.1,1.1r -k 9 | cut -c 50-
```

If you want to see the whole output of `ls -l`, just leave out the `cut` part.