# How to make 'grep' work like in Ubuntu?

Tags: terminal, search, compatibility

I tried to use `grep` to match one pattern on the terminal, but n
o any result comes out.

```
$ grep -R 'networks'
grep: warning: recursive search of stdin
```

I knew `grep` on macOS is based on BSD while `grep` on Ubuntu is based on GNU.

How to make 'grep' work on macOS like in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

When the `-R` option is used, MacOS `grep` requires you to explicitly give it a directory to search; for example, specify `.` to recursively search the current directory:

```
grep -R 'networks' .
```

Answer (score 20):

Long term, it's probably best to install the tools based on GNU or run Ubuntu virtually. Both are available for free.

`brew install coreutils` (to run the `brew` command you need to install homebrew from https://brew.sh) will put the GNU versions of the tools in your path. Look for the `ggrep` command and possibly a standalone `grep` package to install as the **coreutils** does tend to change over time what it includes.

(EDIT: **Note that as of 2018**, [`grep` specifically needs to be installed separately from `coreutils`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/grep) as follows:

```
$ brew install grep
$ ggrep sometext file.txt     # Note the executable is called ggrep with two G's
```

and has a unique executable name `ggrep` with two G's.)

Also searching here for GNU or coreutils will be helpful for context and tips/tricks.

- [Is it possible to get the full suite of unix options for the command line tools on OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90921/is-it-possible-to-get-the-full-suite-of-unix-options-for-the-command-line-tools/90926?s=6|0.2749#90926)
- [Removing the builtin command-line utilities from PATH, zsh](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110209/removing-the-builtin-command-line-utilities-from-path-zsh/110211?s=4|0.3407#110211)
- [How to have GNU's date in OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231224/how-to-have-gnus-date-in-os-x/231227?s=17|0.2018#231227)
- [Make ls command sort by file type (e.g. directories and file extension)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39885/make-ls-command-sort-by-file-type-e-g-directories-and-file-extension/39920?s=15|0.2064#39920)

Comment: Note that at least now `grep` is not included in the `coreutils` package in `brew` but in its own package called `grep`

Comment: Note also that the executable is called `ggrep` (leading g) now.

Comment: Thanks @dotancohen - feel free to just edit an answer if you’re sure of the situation. There is revision history and we can always chat if a change is unclear to one person or needs further review/adjustment. +1 for the comment - thanks again